# Why can't I handle 300 get responses with async?

Tags: asynchronous, python-requests, get

As part of my homework project, I'm working with [imdb.com](https://imdb.com) pages.

For one task I need to make 320 get-requests to turn them into beautifulsoup objects later on.

I'm trying to do that the async way and so far I got this:

```
def get_tasks(session, url_links):
    tasks = []
    num = 1 # debugging purposes
    for url in url_links:
        tasks.append(session.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en', 'X_FORWARDED_FOR': '2.21.184.0'},  ssl=False))
        time.sleep(1) # avoid 503 status_code
        print(f"Number of responses get_tasks: {num}") # debugging purposes
        num += 1 # debugging purposes
    return tasks
```

```
# Getting response.texts
results = []

async def get_response_texts(url_links):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session, url_links)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        num = 1
        for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.text())
            print(f"{num} responses processed") # debugging purposes
            num += 1
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'Asynchronous execution: Finished in {t2 - t1} seconds\n')
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = [a list of urls to films as strings]
    asyncio.run(get_response_texts(links))
    print(len(results))
```

Here comes the problem: When I process 100 requests, things seem all right, but when I make 300, I get `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError`.

Why is it so and how can I avoid that and make 320 requests asynchronously?

Comment: Use a connection pool and find a concurrency level that works, but I'd expect IMDB to eventually block or rate limit you if you keep it up.

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you please elaborate on that? I started learning async only now. What should I read?

Comment: I don't know the tool you're using, but https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html looks like what you want. `conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)`